# Numpy array of images wrong dimension Python and Keras

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras, resnet

I'm building an image classifier and trying to compute the features for a dataset using keras but my array dimension is not on the right format. I'm getting

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (324398, 1)
```

My code is this:

```
import glob
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50

def extract_resnet(X):  
    # X : images numpy array
    resnet_model = ResNet50(input_shape=(image_h, image_w, 3), 
    weights='imagenet', include_top=False)  # Since top layer is the fc layer used for predictions
    features_array = resnet_model.predict(X)
    return features_array
filelist = glob.glob('dataset/*.jpg')
myarray = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in filelist])
print(extract_resnet(myarray))
```

So it looks like for some reason the images array is only two dimensional when it should be 4 dimensional. How can I convert `myarray` so that it is able to work with the feature extractor?

Comment: Looks like it expects an array of RGB images.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm feeding it RGB images. Color should be 1 dimension either way, returned array is still 2 dimensions.

Comment: Yes, it expects each RGB image to be in its original, 3D shape.

Comment: From the code he doesn't seem to be reshaping anything though. @Juanvulcano, just random guessing, could it be that the images don't all have the same shape so you're building a list of arrays instead of a tensor?

Comment: @filippo True, that's the case. Any reference on how to resize the images so that I can get the 4d array?

Comment: @Juanvulcano it depends on your specific dataset, you could preprocess it all with something like `scikit-image` or even `ImageMagick` or rescale/randomly crop it on the fly for data augmentation. See also keras' own `ImageDataGenerator` which might be helpful (e.g. you can define a `target_size` and let it do the rescaling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, make sure that all of the images in `dataset` directory have the same size `(image_h, image_w, 3)`:

```
print([np.array(Image.open(fname)).shape for fname in filelist])
```

If they are not, you won't be able to make a mini-batch, so you'll need to select only the subset of suitable images. If the size is right, you can then reshape the array manually:

```
myarray = myarray.reshape([-1, image_h, image_w, 3])
```

... to match ResNet specification exactly.